# How to retrive previous Domain URL in Wp

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, site-url, home-url

One of my firend accidently! Changed the WorsPress domain address to his expired domin address now we can't even connect to WP Login Page and WP is redirecting us to a domain address which does not exist any more!
Can you please let me know how we can retrive the login credential or update the URL through The Database or Configuration Files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the wp-config.php on the server, you can add the following constants that will override the database. This does not save the settings but will at least get you viewing the site again.

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'url_to_wordpress_core_files' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'url_to_wordpress_front_end' );
```

There is also a `RELOCATE` constant that will make the changes to the database - see the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method) on how to do that.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Welcher, thanks for reply I already tried adding these two lines into the functions.php and wp-config as well like update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com'); which I update the http://example.com to our own domain but I am getting Fatal error on top of white page when I add them to wp-cinfig and nothing change on functions.php

Comment: Can you post the Fatal Error you are getting?